# SQLAlchemy can't connect to local MySQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to useSQLAlchemy to create a database, but when I run

```
meta.create_all()
```

I get

```
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)") None None
```

This is my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.databases import mysql
from datetime import datetime
import logging
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import deque

#logging.basicConfig()
#logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)

#meta = MetaData('sqlite:///database.sqlite3')
f = open("db.txt", "r") # db.txt should contain text like "mysql://realboy@localhost/realboy?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0"
db_path = f.read()
f.close()

db = create_engine(db_path)
meta = MetaData(db)
users = Table('users', meta,
  Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
  Column("username", String(100), unique=True),
  Column("password", String(100)),
  Column("explored_friends", Boolean, default=False),
  Column("exhausted_friends", Boolean, default=False),
  Column("explored_tweets", Boolean, default=False),
  Column("edge_count", Integer, default=0),
  Column("group", Integer, default=-1),
  mysql_charset='utf8'
)

meta.create_all()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your MySQL server's socket is likely not at /tmp/mysql.sock so the driver can't connect. Mine is at /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock, for example. SQLAlchemy is likely using the mysqclient driver which takes a unix_socket parameter. To take advantage, try using that in the connection URI like so:

```
mysql://realboy@localhost/realboy?unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

To find out where your servers's socket actually is, try looking inside /etc/mysql/my.cnf [or whatever your server uses for config]